# Javascript not defined error, when adding elements to array

Tags: javascript

I have a Json array, that I'm parsing into a javascript object array.

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8084/RestandJson/api/Person');
  request.onload = function() {
    var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    // renderhtml(data);
    addPerson(data);
  };
  request.send();
});
```

I have made an addPerson function to add a user-defined object into the list.

```
addPerson = (data) => {
  var fName = document.getElementById("fname");
  var lName = document.getElementById("lname");
  var age = document.getElementById("age");
  var id = data.pop()+1;
  const person = {fName, lName, age, id};
  data.add(person);
}
```

when the function is called I get 'addPerson is not defined' as an error. Why is this?

here is my entire file:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var root = document.getElementById("root");


btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8084/RestandJson/api/Person');
    request.onload = function(){
      var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
      //renderhtml(data);
      addPerson(data);

    };
    request.send();

});



renderhtml = (data) => {
let htmlString = " ";

for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    htmlString += "<p> " + data[i].fName +" " +  data[i].lName + "</p>"
}



addPerson = (data) => {
    var fName = document.getElementById("fname");
    var lName = document.getElementById("lname");
    var age = document.getElementById("age");
    var id = data.pop()+1;
    const person = {fName, lName, age, id};
    data.push(person);

}



root.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString);
}
```

Comment: same error occurs

Comment: The error means that `addPerson()` is defined in a scope such that it's not accessible from the XHR callback. Without seeing more code it's impossible to be more precise.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have edited the code, so we can see the entire file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you didn't close your `renderHTML` function properly, it should be like this:

```
renderhtml = (data) => {
  let htmlString = " ";

  for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      htmlString += "<p> " + data[i].fName +" " +  data[i].lName + "</p>"
  }
} // <-- Add closing bracket to renderHTML function here

addPerson = (data) => {
  var fName = document.getElementById("fname");
  var lName = document.getElementById("lname");
  var age = document.getElementById("age");
  var id = data.pop()+1;
  const person = {fName, lName, age, id};
  data.push(person);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the whole addPerson function outside the renderhtml function, most probably because that addPerson function is inside the renderhtml function

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  While this answer is good, you could make it great by adding the revised code, see other answers for what I mean by this.  As it stands, it is more of a comment than an answer.  As this is a "coding" site code is always good and does not always have to be large, just illustrative.

Comment: My apologies, thanks for letting me know @MarkSchultheiss :)